# How to do sum of a column with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

```
  var GrandTotal = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(cols => Convert.ToDecimal(cols.Field<string>("TotalPrice")));
```

is Giving Error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'
```

How can I Correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TotalPrice` column contains decimal values, but you are trying to cast row field value to `string`. Cast to `decimal` directly instead:

```
var GrandTotal = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("TotalPrice"));
```